# AWS Inspector2 not working with default Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-ssm, aws-security-hub

I'm trying to use the aws inspector service (the new one, not the classic one) and I created an Amazon Linux 2 instance, and I attached the AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore role and so the instance appeared in the fleet manager but the aws inspector doesn't find any package vulnerabilities in the instance. I can only make it work when I choose the "Amazon Linux 2 AMI with Amazon Inspector Agent" image. Is there something missing to make it work in the default instance?

I already tried using the default Amazon Linux 2 instance, but it only worked with the instance with the agent already installed

Comment: This might be helpful: [amazon-inspector-ec2-scanning](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/amazon-inspector-ec2-scanning). Make sure SSM agent is installed. If you are using AWS Inspector2 you don't need to install Inspector Agent (I _think_ it's an AWS Inspector Classic requirement).

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon Inspector Agent needs to be installed in order to run the Amazon Inspector. If you want to use the default AMI or any other AMI. You can use userdata to install the Amazon Inspector Agent or run SSM document to do the installation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/inspector/v1/userguide/inspector_installing-uninstalling-agents.html#install-linux

Comment: I tried installing this but it still didn't work. I am using AWS Inspector v2